# can I compare orignal arima with sqrted arima model?

Tags: arima, data-transformation, likelihood, aic, model-comparison

I use arima to fit my data. I use data and it's root sqrted respectively. Can I compare two model by comparing their AIC, loglikelihood etc.?
Thanks.

Comment: No, not directly. You can find multiple previous threads discussing that, some of them are [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aic+data-transformation). Perhaps one of them is a duplicate of yours?

Comment: Thank you very much